# Is Tomcat or Jetty a better container for Geoserver on Windows

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache, tomcat, jetty

My Understanding is that Geoserver can be run in the default Jetty Environment or in Tomcat on Windows Server 2008 R2

GeoWebCache uses Tomcat as its container in its installation instructions.

Which is better for Geoserver, Tomcat or Jetty and why?

UPDATE (Thanks @BradHards)

> Application is stand alone Geoserver talking via Private LAN to a Standalone Postgres/PostGIS Server delivering up to 4 WMS tiled layers to the internet
>
> Up-time needs to be 99%
>
> Load is undetermined at this time. Deployment of additional servers is expected when load reaches a predetermined limit, which we are trying to assess.
>
> Environment: Windows Server 2008 (32 Bit), Public Facing. Currently running Geoserver on Jetty
>
> Updates: only when they will provide performance benefits or additional features that will improve the WMS Layers delivered.

Comment: The answer is "it depends". What are you trying to do? What is the deployment scenario? What is your management approach?

Comment: @BradHards IIS7+ on a server running a proxy public facing. Windows 2008 R2 behind it on a private network as a dedicated machine running only Geowebserver. Management via RDP direct on the server.

Comment: Think above the low level technical level - what are the integrating applications? What load? How often will you update it? What uptime requirements? Please edit your question (not just add comments) to include those details.

Comment: If you are not sure of your load yet you probably have a low load (Maybe??) so why not host it on openshift for free and scale up if need be https://blog.openshift.com/build-your-own-google-maps-and-more-with-geoserver-on-openshift/

Comment: In my experience there is no question to which the best answer is ever Tomcat.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is insuficient information in the question to answer this question one way or another